# Problems with locally stored data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsuserdefaults

I am having a very weird problem. Below I will show you the code that is giving me problems. This part `if defaults == "" {` is for some reason giving me this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I cannot understand why. Let me show you more of my code to better understand:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


@IBAction func nextThing(sender: AnyObject) {
    helloName = nameInput.text!
    helloSurname = surnameInput.text!

    if defaults == "" { // This is where the error is, found out using breakpoint`
```

The weird thing is that this code worked before I added Firebase to my code?

Hope you can help me as it is really frustrating.

Comment: add your firebase code.. and what is `defaults`

Comment: var defaults is right above the code part. I don't know why it won't be in the code tag. I do not use any firebase code as of yet, I just added firebase to my project and I wondered if that had something to do with it?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not a String that's why you are getting an error. If you are checking to see if a key exists you should do defaults.objectForKey("YourKey") == nil. Or if you know the key contains a string you can do "" instead of nil.

Comment: That did it @AJB! I would like to accept it as an answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

If you want to check if key exists:

```
defaults.objectForKey("YourKey") == nil
```

If you know the type that the key contains, you can check with an object of that type, e.g. String:

```
defaults.objectForKey("YourKey") == ""
```